# Search questions from my favourited list?

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks

I have *favourited* lots of question and every time I want to view some question I need to search for that question, which is really annoying. It's difficult to remember the keywords and the exact question I am looking for.

I want to suggest adding a feature which allows you to search any question from your list of favourited questions from a textbox (much like google autocomplete) or have some folder like structure to manage it.

I work on Javascript, jQuery, MySQL, PHP and lately Python and it is difficult to manage these questions.

**Update**:
I still feel that this feature could still improve,rather than having a different page for it,it would be very convinient for evry single user to just click the favourites menu tab and have an autocomplete feature to the search bar.much like google.

Comment: "How do I approach the SO folks to add this feature on their site?" - you just did.

Comment: I've edited your question to be a feature-request instead; this is the right place to post such requests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *already* search in just your favorited questions.

In the search-box, add `infavorites:mine` to the search criteria, plus whatever keywords you were looking for. You can add tags by putting the tagname in square brackets:

```
infavorites:mine [python]
```

will list all favorites with the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag, for example.

Comment: but i think It would be better if we can have it on the same page...

Comment: @martijn I believe the second example of the search should be the same as the first ("infavorites").

Comment: `favorites:mine [python]` should be `infavorites:mine [python]`. I suggested an edit but it was too insignificant, so it was rejected.

Comment: @chuex: right, yes, that's a typo on my part.